# Not able to get values of all elements in XML using XmlNodeList and XmlNamespaceManager

Tags: c#, xml

I am parsing below XML. I need value 'x2@email.com'.I am able to get the list of nodes successfully, but the problem is that with each iteration I am still getting 'x1@email.com' from the first group of 'Info' element.

XML:

```
<ClaimAdminContact xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.Models">
  <claimAdminID>T1</claimAdminID>
  <contactInfo>
    <Info>
      <desc>Level 1 Notifications</desc>
      <emailAddress>x1@email.com</emailAddress>
      <orgNum>1234</orgNum>
      <type>T2</type>
    </Info>
    <Info>
      <desc>Level 2 Notifications</desc>
      <emailAddress>x2@email.com</emailAddress>
      <orgNum i:nil="true"/>
      <type>T2</type>
    </Info>
    <Info>
      <desc>Level 3 Notifications</desc>
      <emailAddress>x3@email.com</emailAddress>
      <orgNum i:nil="true"/>
      <type>T2</type>
    </Info>
  </contactInfo>
</ClaimAdminContact>
```

I have tried full xpath but still not able to get the next set of values. Below is the code that I am using to parse xml.

Code:

```cs
      XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlEmail.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("MsBuild", xmlns);
            var contactInfo = xmlEmail.SelectNodes("/MsBuild:ClaimAdminContact/MsBuild:contactInfo/*", nsmgr);

            foreach (XmlNode item in contactInfo)
            {
                _notificationDesc = item.SelectSingleNode("//MsBuild:desc", nsmgr).InnerText;
                _reviewEmail = item.SelectSingleNode("//MsBuild:emailAddress", nsmgr).InnerText;
                _orgNum = item.SelectSingleNode("//MsBuild:orgNum", nsmgr).InnerText;
            }
```

Please

Comment: Can you use `System.Xml.Linq`? It'd be super easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var results = doc.Descendants(ns + "Info").Select(x => new
            {
                desc = (string)x.Element(ns + "desc"),
                email = (string)x.Element(ns + "emailAddress"),
                orgNum = (string)x.Element(ns + "orgNum"),
                type = (string)x.Element(ns + "type")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jdweng ! I tried this before, but it wasn't fetching any data. Therefore I removed namespace from xml and then used this method. It is working now.

Comment: You should not be modifying the xml and removing the namespaces.  The xml posted works.  Is the posted xml exactly the same and the one you are running?  I can easily fix code if I had the xml that is failing.

Comment: I just updated the xml with another namespace. The xml that I have is more like it.

Comment: I updated code.  It took me about 30 seconds to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Using `System.Xml.Linq`:

```
var xmlFile = @"myxml.xml";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
var infos = xDoc.Descendants("Info");
foreach (var info in infos)
{
    var email = info.Element("emailAddress").Value;
}
```

---

### EDIT: How to work with namespaces

If you have multiple namespaces and want to work with that, then you must specify the namespaces like below. Removing namespaces from the file is hardly a good idea.

```
var xmlFile = @"C:\Users\gurudeniyas\Desktop\myxml.xml";
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.Models";
XNamespace nsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
var infos = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Info");
foreach (var info in infos)
{
    var email = info.Descendants(ns + "emailAddress").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    Console.WriteLine(email);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sach ! I tried this before, but it wasn't fetching any data. Therefore I removed namespace from xml and then parsed the xml. It is working now. I have posted my solution.

Comment: That's a bad approach. You shouldn't remove namespaces in order to process `XML`. This example works with namespaces as it is.

Comment: it wasn't working for me. I have updated the xml that I posted above. I have two namespaces in the root element.

Comment: @aaycee see the edit. Removing namespaces is never a good idea, instead you must work with them.

Comment: Thank you ! I have changed my code to keep namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge I was facing in parsing xml was the namespace attribute in the root element. It was preventing my code to parse the usual way and that was the reason why I tried using 'XmlNamespaceManager'. I decided to remove the namespace from the xml.

I used below recursive method to remove namespace from xml and everything worked!! I am not sure if this is the optimal way, but I was able to achieve what I wanted.

```cs
public XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement root)
        {
            return new XElement(
                root.Name.LocalName,
                root.HasElements ?
                    root.Elements().Select(x => RemoveAllNamespaces(x)) :
                    (object)root.Value

                );
        }
```

Calling Code:

```cs
XElement noNsDoc = RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement.Parse(xmlString));

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(noNsDoc.ToString());
```

Comment: DO NOT REMOVE NAMESPACES.  IT IS NOT NECESSARY.  Namespace are in the XML so exceptions will occur if the data is corrupt (or not valid). Removing namespaces allows bad data to be processed.